# Simple cron job does not show in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to create a very basic cron job on Google App Engine. After I deploy my project, corn job does not show in my application>Cron jobs. I have corn.xml in my Webapps directory and also configured the servlet url in web.xml. 
I have also followed the following tutorial and created an application to test the corn job in the tutorial but cron job still does not show:

http://rominirani.com/2009/11/16/episode-9-using-the-cron-service-to-run-scheduled-tasks/

Comment: Maybe you just need to call it cron.xml? It's not "corn".

Comment: correction:I placed corn.xml in my WEB-INF directory

Comment: Thank you Stefan!!! That was the problem.

Comment: Leo thats great news please, would you mind explaining how you solved the issue and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error in filename:
corn.xml > cron.xml

The file goes in the WEB-INF directory. When you deploy to Google Cloud Project you should get a response similar to "Updating Crons" after the deployment is complete. They will then appear under Compute > App Engine > Task Queue > Cron Jobs.